# Use Ubuntu as VPN Gateway router (internet traffic only over VPN)

Tags: 14.04, openvpn

I have a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 14.04.3 that I would like to

1. use as a Gateway router.
2. connect to an OpenVPN server from this VM, and have all forwarding to the internet via VPN
3. connect to local machines directly (not over VPN)

I followed instructions from [here](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202721486-Using-Linux-Virtual-Machine-instead-of-a-router-for-VPN) to setup the forwarding, which worked fine. My iptable rules (in a up.sh file) are

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o tun0 -i eth0 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

The first rule is the one I added to allow forwarding to local resources.

I have a similar down.sh file to tear down the forwarding (or so, I hoped)

```
sudo iptables -D POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -D FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -D FORWARD -o tun0 -i eth0 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

I also executed the following command to enable forwarding

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
```

In my openvpn config.conf file, I have the scripts set to run via the following commands

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
down /etc/openvpn/down.sh
```

On VM startup, the up script is run and traffic is forwarded over the VPN (although the first few packets seem to be sent over the regular connection). To test the down script, I then do,

```
sudo killall openvpn
```

It looks like the script is run successfully, as all my iptable rules are removed. However, traffic is now forwarded over my regular internet connection (eth0).

How can I get the traffic forwarding to stop if VPN disconnects or is no longer operational? Ideally, I would like access to local resources at all times and the internet only via VPN (from my client machines).

Thanks

Comment: hi, I need same thing, but I can't connect client through ubuntu guest machine. I correctly connected vpn, I can access on Internet in guest machine. I set all rules in iptables as hma suggest. But when set gateway in other clients in my lan, they not have access to internet. I see using tcpdump that nothing incoming to guest machine. Maybe I wrong something in virtual box properties ? I set bridged mode. Any suggest ? this is my question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/835132/ubuntu-guest-as-vpn-gateway